# Mathematical operations on tolerances

Tags: arithmetic

This question is about manufacturing tolerances; for instance, a manufactured component expressed as "$5 \pm 0.3\,\mathrm{in}$" may acceptably be no larger than 5.3 in and no smaller than 4.7 in.

I know how to perform mathematical operations on uncertainties; since uncertanties are expressed statistically, adding two uncertain values involves adding the root of the sum of the squares of the uncertanties. [Details here.](http://www.rit.edu/cos/uphysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html)

However, tolerances *aren't* statistical; they express the intent of the designer. In addition, tolerances may be asymmetrical. Let's say I have two dimensions with tolerances:

$$ X = 50\pm3\,\mathrm{mm} \\ Y = 30^{+3}_{-0}\,\mathrm{mm}$$

**How would I calculate the tolerances for $(X+Y)$ and $(X-Y)$?**

Illustration for $(X+Y)$:

[image]

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are the critical dimensions for the intended use, but the machinist needs to start with $(X+Y)$ to cut the initial block of material.